# How to retrieve image url saved into models in views

Tags: python, django, django-models, file-upload, django-views

I want to fetch image URL which is successfully getting stored in database using models.py 
Now I want to fetch url or location of image in a string variable in views.py

My models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    document_id = models.AutoField
    document_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, default="")
    document_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', default="", blank=False, null=False)
    document_desc = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="", blank=False, null=False)
    document_date = models.DateField()
```

here is views.py

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['doc_img']:
        document = Document()
        document.document_name = request.POST.get('doc_name')
        document.document_img = request.FILES['doc_img']
        document.document_desc = request.POST.get('doc_desc')
        document.document_date = request.POST.get('doc_date')
        document.save()
        doc = Document.objects.all()
        img_path = doc[0].document_img

        return HttpResponse(img_path) 

    else:
        return HttpResponse('Failed To Upload')
```

I know we can show image in html template by

```
<img src='{{doc.0.document_img}}'>
```

but i want it in a python variable

Can anyone Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `relative` path then just do the...

```
img_path = doc[0].document_img.url
```

And for the `absolute` path...

```
img_path = settings.MEDIA_URL + doc[0].document_img.url
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job.

```
img_path = doc[0].document_img.url
```